# How to show that there exists a sequence in $[0,1]$ such that the set of accumulation points of the sequence is $[0,1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, compactness

This is related to homework but I am trying to find a special case first and see if I can generalize it. The problem is to construct some sequence $(x_n)$ in $[0,1]$ such that the accumulation points of $(x_n)$ are the points in the interval $[0,1]$.

I am extremely stuck and honestly have almost no idea how to approach the problem. I was given a hint to consider the subcover formulation of compactness for the interval, but I couldn't identify how that would help me. Intuitively it seems that I should somehow be able to define a sequence which in essence goes through the entire interval. For instance the sequence
$$ (0, 1/2, 1, 3/4, 2/4, 1/4, 0, 1/8, 2/8, 3/8, 4/8\ldots)$$
seems to have the properties I hope for, but I cannot turn this intuition to rigorous mathematics.

Edit: Is it possible to glue together a sequence which consists of sequence that are known to have accumulation points? So for instance if $a \in [0,1]$ we know that the sequence
$$ x_n = a - \frac{1}{n}$$
Has an accumulation point $a$. The problem is that there are infinite $a$ from which to choose from.

Comment: It would be easier if you didn't skip terms ...

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @DavidMitra : I'm not sure he skipped any terms.  ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The sequence appears to be odd numbers over powers of $2$.  When the denominator is $4$ he went downward: first $3$ then $1$, and when it was $8$ he started going upward $1,3,\ldots$.  And certainly that is one sequence that will do the job. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: What about if you just enumerate the rationals?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to write that the sequence I conjectured to work basically goes through the sequence by going to its end points, and then filling in the intervals. So first we start with 0, 1/2 and 1, next we go back down the sequence by going through 3/4 and 1/4, then we keep going and in this way we always pick the half-way point between the intervals.

Comment: I mean, go down to $3/4$, then $2/4$ (was skipped), then $1/4$, ...

Comment: Now I understand what you mean, I will edit the sequence I presented to make it clearer.

Comment: Then if $r$ is in $[0,1]$, for any integer $n$, $r\in [k/2^n, (k+1)/2^n]$ for some $k$ and the  endpoints of these  intervals are members of your sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac 1 2, \underbrace{{}\  \frac 1 4, \frac 3 4\  {}}_{\text{denominator}=4}, \underbrace{\frac 1 8, \frac 3 8, \frac 5 8, \frac 7 8}_{\text{denominator}=8}, \underbrace{\frac 1 {16}, \frac 3 {16}, \frac 5 {16}, \frac 7 {16}, \frac 9 {16}, \frac {11}{16}, \frac{13}{16}, \frac{15}{16}}_{\text{denominator}=16}, \ldots 
$$

To show that every point in $x\in[0,1]$ is an accumulation point of this sequence you need to show that for every $\varepsilon>0$, no matter how small, one of the fractions above is between $x\pm\varepsilon$.  For that it is enough to show that the length of the interval, $2\varepsilon$, is less than the distance $2/2^n$ between consecutive terms in the sequence.  The number $\varepsilon>0$ cannot be a lower bound of the seqence $1/2,1/4,1/8,1/16,\ldots$ because $1/\varepsilon$ cannot be an upper bound of the sequence $1,2,4,8,16,\ldots$.  To prove that, suppose the latter sequence has a least upper bound $a$.  Some power of $2$ must be bigger than $a/2$ since otherwise $a/2$ would be an upper bound, so what about $2$ times that power of $2$?  It is more than $a$ and we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

Fractions $a/b$ such that $a+b=1$ and $a\le b$: $0/1$

Fractions $a/b$ such that $a+b=2$ and $a\le b$: $0/2$, $1/1$

Fractions $a/b$ such that $a+b=3$ and $a\le b$: $0/3$, $1/2$

Fractions $a/b$ such that $a+b=4$ and $a\le b$: $0/4$, $1/3$, $2/2$

etc.

If you don't want to repeat terms, you may add the condition $\gcd(a,b)=1$. But don't forget the $0$.